# Unable to update UI after data is being set in Subscribe to show breadcrumb in angular-typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a logic to show breadcrumb on my page using RoutesRecognized and pairwise as below

**ngOnInit**

```
 this.router.events
        .pipe(filter((evt: any) => evt instanceof RoutesRecognized), pairwise())
        .subscribe((events: RoutesRecognized[]) => {
            let prevUrl = events[0].urlAfterRedirects.toLowerCase().split('/');
            var data = prevUrl[prevUrl.length - 1];
            var urlString = data.split("-");
            urlString.forEach(data => {
                this.backTo += data[0].toUpperCase() + data.substring(1) + ' ';
            });
        });
```

and my **UI**

```
<a class="col-md-6 float-left" routerLink="." (click)="onBackClick()">&lt; Back {{ backTo }}</a>
```

the issue is when I debug I can see the data being set in the variable, but it doesn't show on UI.
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Angular can't detect the changes when setting the value inside subscribe, you can create a **BehaviorSubject** to fix that

```
backTo = "";
backTo$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>(this.backTo);
```

and do this changes

```
this.router.events
    .pipe(filter((evt: any) => evt instanceof RoutesRecognized), pairwise())
    .subscribe((events: RoutesRecognized[]) => {
        let prevUrl = events[0].urlAfterRedirects.toLowerCase().split('/');
        var data = prevUrl[prevUrl.length - 1];
        var urlString = data.split("-");
        urlString.forEach(data => {
            this.backTo += data[0].toUpperCase() + data.substring(1) + ' ';
        });
        this.backTo$.next(this.backTo); // add this line
    });
```

and in your template

```
<a>&lt; Back {{ backTo$ | async }}</a>
```

another solution is to trigger the change manually using
**ChangeDetectorRef**

Comment: I tried the solution you provided and tried using Change DetetectorRef... neither worked, when I did console log both backTo and backTo$ had the required value but still didn't show on the UI